# Kafka Deserialization Error: No type information in headers and no default type provided

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am attempting to send a custom payload (object) from the producer to the consumer. The payload is a simple class with three or four fields. I'm encountering an issue with Kafka while deserializing messages, and I'm relatively new to Kafka. The error message I'm getting is:

> Error: No type information in headers and no default type provided. Error deserializing key/value for partition slack_command_event-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.

Here are the relevant code snippets from my Kafka configuration:

`ProducerConfig`

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SlackCommandProducerConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean("slashCommandProducerFactory")
    public ProducerFactory<String, SlashCommandPayload> slackCommandProducerFactory() {
        var props = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props,() -> null,() -> new SlashCommandSerializer<>(SlashCommandPayload .class));
    }

    @Bean("slackCommandKafkaTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<String, SlashCommandPayload> slackCommandKafkaTemplate(@Qualifier("slashCommandProducerFactory") ProducerFactory<String, SlashCommandPayload> slackCmdProducerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(slackCmdProducerFactory);
    }
}
```

`Consumer Config`

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SlackCommandConsumerConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "slackCmdConsumerConfig")
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SlashCommandPayload> slackCmdConsumerConfig() {
        var kafkaProps = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        //kafkaProps.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        var props = new HashMap<>(kafkaProps);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,() -> null, () -> new JsonDeserializer<>(SlashCommandPayload.class));
    }
}
```

`Serializer`

```
public class SlashCommandSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {
    private final Gson gson = GsonFactory.createSnakeCase(SlackConfig.DEFAULT);

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String data, T o) {
        if (data == null || o == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return gson.toJson(o).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error serializing JSON message", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        Serializer.super.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

`Deserializer`

```
public class SlashCommandDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T> {
    private final Gson gson = GsonFactory.createSnakeCase(SlackConfig.DEFAULT);

    private Class<T> destinationClass;


    public SlashCommandDeserializer(Class<T> destinationClass) {
        this.destinationClass = destinationClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public SlashCommandPayload deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return gson.fromJson(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), destinationClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error deserializing message", e);
        }
    }
}
```

`Payload`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SlashCommandPayload {

    private String id;
    private String command;
    private String query;
    private String responseUrl;

}
```

I am using the below code to send the payload

```
private final KafkaTemplate<String, SlashCommandPayload> kafkaSlashCommandTemplate;

public SlackEvent(@Qualifier("slackCommandKafkaTemplate") KafkaTemplate<String, SlashCommandPayload> kafkaSlashCommandTemplate){
  this.kafkaSlashCommandTemplate = kafkaSlashCommandTemplate;
}


public void handleSlackSlashCommand(SlashCommandRequest slashCommandRequest) {
    var payload = new SlashCommandPayload();

    payload.setId(slashCommandRequest.getPayload().getTeamId());
    payload.setCommand(slashCommandRequest.getPayload().getCommand());
    payload.setQuery(slashCommandRequest.getPayload().getText());
    payload.setResponseUrl(slashCommandRequest.getResponseUrl());

  kafkaSlashCommandTemplate.send("slack_command_event", 
    slashCommandRequest.getContext().getTeamId(), payload);
}
```

And the below code to receive the payload

```
@KafkaListener(id = "slack_command_event_consumer", topics = "slack_command_event", concurrency = "1")
    public void processSlackCommandEvent(SlashCommandPayload event) {
        var kafkaPayload = new SlackCommandEventPayload();
        kafkaPayload.setId(event.getId());
        kafkaPayload.setQuery(event.getQuery());
        kafkaPayload.setResponseUrl(event.getResponseUrl());
        handler.processCommandEvent(kafkaPayload);
    }
```

I suspect the issue might be related to deserialization. I've included the relevant parts of my code, including the serialization and deserialization logic. Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this Kafka error would be greatly appreciated. If you need additional information, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, YourDeserializer.class); You are missing setting deserialzier in consumer config

Comment: @mlecz didn't work out.

Comment: oh, try VALUE_DESERIALIZER instead of KEY (or maybe you need both, one StringDeserialzier for key and yours for VALUE)

Comment: Spring Kafka has a builtin json deserializer. Why write your own?

Comment: @mlecz Didn't work out again

Comment: @OneCricketeer. Thats a good question. When i just write private final KafkaTemplate<String, SlashCommandPayload> kafkaSlashCommandTemplate; i get SlashCommandPayload is not of type Kafka bean. So i used Producer Factory and Consumer Factory to resolve the issue.

Comment: That's a producer setting. Your error is from consumer side. As mentioned, you've not shared your consumer factory. See similar error (but different deserializer) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114470/2308683

Comment: Oh, I skipped reading... `new JsonDeserializer`? So you are using this. Then, why show your Gson deserializer if not using it? Otherwise, you need to use JsonSerializer in your Producer Factory... The Kafka bean error can be solved separately. It still doesn't require custom serializer classes (Spring defaults to use Jackson for json, you don't really need Gson)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am happy to make changes. To be honest, i don't need a custom serializer and deserializer. I can stick with Json Serializer and Deserializer too.

Comment: @JamesKJ, I am facing the same error. Did you get a fix?

Answer (score 0):

When JsonDeserializer class from spring-kafka is used, it defaults to look for type information in headers.

This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#json-serde), and can be disabled by not using it (i.e using your own deserializer that doesn't depend on Spring-kafka functions), or adding `JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false` in the consumer config, but then also adding the default value type for your deserialization class.

Also see settings for `JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES` and Mapping Types for fully configuring the JSON deserializer correctly